# Working with state objects in Redux (basic)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, redux

I'm new to Redux/React and am having problems working with state objects.

I have initialised my state as in index.js below but am getting this error

> `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child
>   (found: object with keys {text}). If you meant to render a collection
>   of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method
>   of ShowTweetComponent.`

index.js

```
const initialState = {
  text: 'test successful'
} 

let store = createStore( 
  twitterApp,       
  initialState,     
  applyMiddleware(  
    thunkMiddleware 
  )
) 

console.log('1 - index.js loaded')

render( 
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('LoadApp')
)
```

Here is my action

```
function getTweetData(json) {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_TWEETS,
    tweet: json.status_text,
    receivedAt: Date.now().toString()
  }
}

function fetchTweets() {

  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`/api/twitter`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(getTweetData(json)))
  }


}

export function fetchTweetsIfNeeded() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch(fetchTweets())
  }
}
```

And here's my reducer

```
const displayData = (state = [], action) => {

  switch (action.type) {

    case REQUEST_TWEETS:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          text: action.tweet
        }
      ]

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

If there's any extra info you need please let me know. I can only get it to work when working with `exampleState = 'this is my message!'`

UPDATE:
Here's the repo (see client folder for react stuff) https://github.com/jaegerbombb/twitter-api-test

Comment: Has nothing to do with state or redux. This is a React error, most likely in `App`. Could you show us that?

Comment: Specifically the `ShowTweetComponent` it seems

Comment: Of course, I've added a link in the description. Let me know if you want more info. I already looked at where the error references but couldn't understand the problem on my own

Comment: I think you are trying to render an array (display the entire state in html?) and react complaints that its not possible to do so. Hence the suggestion to use `map` to show individual values. Have tried using `Array.map` while displaying your state in the template?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sounds like it's along the right lines. Just struggling slightly to actually implement that at the moment but will let you know if I succeed

Comment: Ended up treating my state object as an.... object. So I just used JSON.stringify and console.log to get an output that I could actually see for my state. Then I followed this: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html and got the Object rest spread transform babel plugin to clean up my spread operator in the reducer.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwritting `this.props.children` with your redux state (in your `twitterContainer.js`).  I am not sure if this a good idea. React expect `children` to be a `node`, but it is getting an array (from your twitterApp reducer).

For you code, you can just change the `children` key to another name in your `twitterContainer.js` and `twitterComponent.js`